# Maximum number of digitsAfterDecimal option in dygraphs for r

Tags: r, dygraphs

I have a dygraph for which I would like to display 5 digits after the decimal on the y-axis. I tried:

```
dyOptions(digitsAfterDecimal=5)
```

However, only 3 decimal places are shown in the plot. But, 5 appear on the legend.

I also tried the following in an attempt to get the extra digits to display:

```
dyAxis("y",axisLabelWidth=100,axisLabelFontSize=1)
```

The font size option does not appear to change anything, and the axis label width changes the spacing between the axis title and the tick labels, and does not accomplish what I am after.

Here is a mini reproducible example:

```
library(dygraphs)

# create sample data
x <- seq(101,200,by=1)
y <- round(runif(100, 0.0, 1.0), digits=5)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# make the graph and set the decimals option
dygraph(dat, xlab="Distance",ylab="Value",main="dygraphs for R decimals display example") %>%
dyAxis("y",axisLabelWidth=100,axisLabelFontSize=20) %>%
dyOptions(digitsAfterDecimal=5)
```

Which only displays one decimal on the Y axis, despite the options set to display 5.

Comment: The dygraphs library is for javascript (at least according to the tag dropdown). What does this have to do with R? (That is an implicit call for a reproducible question in _full_ R code.

Comment: dygraphs is also an R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dygraphs/index.html I have edited the question to include a reproducible example.

Comment: The 5 digits appears to be reflected in the display of the values as you move the mouse within the plot area. There are no y-axis number in the version I'm seeing.

Comment: I am using the code in a Shiny app, but that really doesn't have anything to do with the problem, perhaps I should have left that part out. The example I show makes the dygraph in regular R, with the same issue I get when I use it in the app.

Comment: Yeah... I see that now. The foint size of 1 was too small, try setting to 20. And the help page tells you "Trailing zeros are not displayed, so with a value of 2 you'll get '0', '0.1', '0.12', '123.45' ,,,   "

Comment: Right, it shows 5 decimals on the legend, but not on the y-axis. You cannot see any values on the y-axis?

Comment: Not until I set the font size to 20

Comment: Okay, that is strange, because the font size option does not change the display for me. I wonder why. I'll edit the question so it shows up for others. I was able to answer this by digging into the help more and noticing that my example has all trailing zeros. If I set the sigFigs option in dyOptions to 5, they display.

Answer (score 1):

## make the graph and set the sig figs option to 5

Because my data and the example data contain trailing zeros as @42 pointed out:

```
dygraph(dat, xlab="Distance",ylab="Value",main="dygraphs for R decimals display example") %>%
  dyAxis("y",axisLabelWidth=80) %>%
  dyOptions(sigFigs=5)
```

However, this adds more decimal places to the x-axis as well, which I would like to avoid. Currently dygraphs for R does not have the sigFigs option for use within dyAxis().